# check if argument to ProcessBuilder is a valid command

Tags: java, process, clojure

I'm working a a Clojure library to simplify subprocess management for a project of mine. It essentially wraps Java's `ProcessBuilder` in a more Clojuric way. One thing I'd like to do is to catch any missing commands -- that is, if a user wants to use `this-command-not-found` as a shell command, my code should throw an exception.

It looks like this is hard, or impossible, to do with `ProcessBuilder`, though. Do I need to somehow get the user's `$PATH` and search through there to check for a valid command, or is there a better way?

**EDIT: This should be done *without* starting the process -- see my comment below.**

Comment: If it is not possible overall, is not my answer much more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course there is a better way than searching `$PATH`: just run the command the user asked you to run. No smarter solution is possible, with ProcessBuilder or any other mechanism, because the set of shells the user could be using is open-ended, and there's no requirement that their shell even have the notion of a `$PATH` for you to search. All you can do is try your best to do what the user wants, and if an error happens let them know.

Comment: Alright; it's unfortunate that that's the best way, but I guess it's not a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

You get `Process` from `ProcessBuilder.start()`.

Then you can read from `Process.getErrorStream()` and under Windows check for

`'this-command-not-found' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear -- I want to do this _without_ starting the process. Consider if said process has a side effect (i.e., `rm`). It shouldn't be started until the user calls it.

Comment: @Peter, if you call rm without parameters it should produce no side effect.

Comment: To automatically pass the output onto the standard outputs, try `process.waitForProcessOutput((Appendable) System.out, (Appendable) System.err)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably execute [`which`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_which.htm) command using ProcessBuilder to know whether a command exist or not. This requires `which` to be present on the system.